# Rails share session variables in multiple threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, session

Is it possible to share session variables in multiple threads?
 I want to run loop in new thread depending on session variable.
The problem is I am changing session variable in main thread and it is not reflected in new thread created?

```
 def log_in(user)      

    begin     

    session[:user_id] = user[:id]

    storeAuthToken(user)

    session[:logged] = true  


Thread.new do


      while true  do      

    if(! session[:logged])    
        break
      else

        begin
        #do something
       sleep 5          
        rescue => e 
        p  e     
        end

      end
    end
  end 

  rescue => e


    end  
end
```

Comment: Share your code that you have tried for this. If you have not tried anything yet, try it first

Comment: Please help me to figure out a way to come out with solution

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are best candidates to introduce in this case. In Rails, the variables that starts with dollar sign ($) are global variables.

Or you may want to try configuration variables or YAML key value pairs that will be available application wide.

Comment: But in this case I am looking at user specific data. So in this case global variables are not working